# Android Camera2: Auto Focus and Exposure

Tags: android, android-camera2

In my Android camera application I'm using the Camera2 API. The application doesn't show the preview of the Camera, and I've implemented it in a way, when a button on the UI is pressed, it takes an image. But the problem is with auto focus and auto exposure. Simply, I need to camera always focused on the middle of its view. So when building the request, I added following properties:

```
captureBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AF_MODE, CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AF_MODE_AUTO);
captureBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AE_MODE, CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AE_MODE_ON);
captureBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AWB_MODE, CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AWB_MODE_AUTO);
captureBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AF_TRIGGER, CameraMetadata.CONTROL_AF_TRIGGER_START);
captureBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AE_PRECAPTURE_TRIGGER, CameraMetadata.CONTROL_AE_PRECAPTURE_TRIGGER_START);
```

But the problem is still the images are not focused.

I have couple of questions:

Do I need to implement some checking in a method inside `CameraCaptureSession.CaptureCallback`?

I also noticed that by the time `onImageAvailable` is called in `ImageReader.OnImageAvailableListener`, the `onCaptureProgressed` method of `CameraCaptureSession.CaptureCallback` is not triggered.

What are the points I'm missing here? Do I need to implement a thread to wait until the camera is focused, which will start by when pressing the take picture button.

Please note that there's no camera preview for this application.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Are you sending only a single capture request? Or are you running a repeating request in the background, and then only issuing a high-resolution capture on button press?

The former won't really work - you have to have a flow of requests to have the autoexposure, focus, and white balance algorithms converge to good values. A single capture won't be properly metered or focused.

Please take a look at the [Camera2Basic](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-Camera2Basic/) sample; if you replace the TextureView in that sample with just a SurfaceTexture (give it a random texture ID and don't call updateTexImage), then you can have no preview.  But it implements focusing and the precapture trigger correctly, which is critical for you here.  For one, the triggers must only be set on one request, and then you do need to watch the capture results coming back to see when the exposure / focus state changes to FOCUSED or CONVERGED.

I'd also recommend the CONTINUOUS_PICTURE focus mode instead of AUTO; it's likely to get you a focused image faster.

Comment: Yes, I was running a single capture request. If I run a repeating request in the background, that means camera is always on right? just like when we are looking at the preview when taking a photo. So If I've understood correctly, if the app is made this way, it'll consume lots of power on the long run?

Comment: If so is there a way that, It'll be like a single request, but before taking the photo, it'll try to focus?

Comment: If you want, you can just turn the camera on when the user hits the shutter button, but this will have substantial latency.  Power on takes ~1 second, converging metering/focus another few hundred ms, and then you can take your picture.  You'll still have to run a repeating request until AF is good and fire the precapture sequence if you want to use flash.

Comment: Thanks Eddy, initial option is working perfectly ok. But with the camera open all the time, 2nd option is bit tricky. Specially it's taking some time to open the camera and finish preparing everything. Anyway I can start with this method.

Comment: @EddyTalvala can you please refer us to a certain book, or a course of urs that talks mainly on camera2/x. u r a camera ninja indeed Eddy.

Comment: You can watch the short presentation at Google I/O from a few years ago: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=92fgcUNCHic&feature=youtu.be&t=29m50s , but I don't have any books to point you to, sorry.